# Retrieving numerical result from function

Tags: function, evaluate, maxima

I am working on a code in maxima and in it I define a function.

```
Ucr(y):=offset+c1[21]+2*sum(realpart(c1[m+20])*cos(2*%pi*(m-1)*y/dp) - imagpart(c1[m+20])*sin(2*%pi*(m-1)*y/dp),m,2,nmax+1);
```

However if I try to evaluate something like Ucr(1) I do not get a number for an answer, I get a big long equation with all the variables and numbers plugged in. I am new to maxima and can not figure out how I can get it to cook down to a nice expression.

I would appreciate any help.

Best,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can give the variables numerical values

```
kill(nmax, dp, offset, c1);
numerval(nmax, 1);
numerval(dp, 1);
numerval(offset, 1);
/* fill a list with dummy values */
c1: makelist(1/m+m*%i, m, 1, ev(nmax, numer)+22);
Ucr(y):=offset+c1[21]+2*sum(realpart(c1[m+20])*cos(2*%pi*(m-1)*y/dp) - imagpart(c1[m+20])*sin(2*%pi*(m-1)*y/dp),m,2,nmax+1);

ev(Ucr(1), numer);
```

Or just bond numerical values at the end

```
kill(nmax, dp, offset, c1);
Ucr(y):=offset+c1[21]+2*sum(realpart(c1[m+20])*cos(2*%pi*(m-1)*y/dp) - imagpart(c1[m+20])*sin(2*%pi*(m-1)*y/dp),m,2,nmax+1);
env: [dp=1, offset=1, nmax=1, c1=makelist(1/m+m*%i, m, 1, 23)];
ev(Ucr(1), env);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping `float(trigreduce(rectform( ... )))` around your function body.